# Conditional Probability in the discrete case

Tags: probability

I am studying this section of probability but get stuck on this problem. **Here is the classic problem:**

Roll a die and then toss as many coins as shown up on the die. Compute the
expected number of Heads.
Let X be the number on the die and let Y be the number of Heads. Fix an x ∈ {1, 2, . . . , 6}.
Given that X = x, Y is Binomial(x,1,2)

I am having hard time understanding the next line:

$P(y \ heads | \ die \ rolls \ x) = P(y \ heads \ in \ x \ coin \ toss) =  \binom{x}{y} \frac{1}{2^x} $

I don't get it because if I use the bin. dsn, I should also multiply by $\frac{1}{2^{x-y}}$ to have the following:

$P(y \ heads | \ die \ rolls \ x) = P(y \ heads \ in \ x \ coin \ toss) =  \binom{x}{y} \frac{1}{2^x}\frac{1}{2^{x-y}}$

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be $\frac{1}{2^y}\frac{1}{2^{x-y}}$ for $y$ heads and $x-y$ tails.  And this is equal to $\frac{1}{2^x}$

Comment: Dah...I need to wake up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You throw the coin $x$ times. Now the probability that the first $y$ are heads and the second $x-y$ are tails is:
$$\frac{1}{2^{y}}\frac{1}{2^{x-y}}=\frac{1}{2^x}$$
But we can choose the $y$ heads out of the $x$ throws in ${x\choose y}$ ways. So:
$$P(y\text{ heads in } x\text{ coin tosses})={x\choose y}\frac{1}{2^x}$$